# Visual studio cannot find nafxcwd.pdb

Tags: c++, mfc, fortran, pdb-files

I am working in a mixed Fortran-C++ programming environment. The C++ project is a static library (`XMLParser.lib`) used to read and write into XML files. It is added as an additional dependency to Fortran project, which is a DLL library (`engine.dll`) used to perform mathematical computations. The Fortran uses CRT (`LIBCMTD`) and C++ is using MFC libraries. As described in [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/148652), this can cause linker error if `LIBCMTD` and `NAFXCWD` libraries are not linked in the correct order. To avoid this issue I had to add `nafxcwd.lib` as an additional dependency to C++ project.

Everything works fine and solution is compiled successfully however, while linking these projects, compiler is compaining that it cannot find `nafxcwd.pdb` file in `$(OUTDIR)` folder (the output folder where C++ static library is created). To work around this issue, I had to copy `nafxcwd.pdb` from Visual Studio folder into my output folder, which is not a practical option since this very specific instruction should be shared with every other programmer in my group. I have tried different options related to creating pdb file (i.e. /Zi, /Z7, and ZI) but none of them seems to be working.

```
2>XMLParser.lib(dumpcont.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(dumpflt.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(arccore.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(arcobj.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(arcex.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(arcstrm.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(dumpinit.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(dumpout.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(afxasert.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(afxmem.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(filecore.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(filetxt.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(filex.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(filest.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
2>XMLParser.lib(array_b.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'nafxcwd.pdb' was not found with 'd:\Debug\XMLParser.lib' or at 'D:\Debug\nafxcwd.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
```

I appreciate if you could help me with the following questions:

1. Why visual studio is looking for `nafxcwd.pdb` in output folder instead of VS folder?
2. Is there any way to embed `nafxcwd.pdb` into `XMLParser.obj` file to ensure that linker will always find it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this problem. In the Fortran project, I added `nafxcwd.lib libcmtd.lib` to additional project dependencies, and added the same libraries to ignore list.